# How can I get the first and third td from a table with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, html-table, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am currently using Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape some website data. 
I'm trying to pull cells from a table which is formatted like so:

```
<tr><td>1<td><td>20<td>5%</td></td></td></td></tr>
```

The problem with the above HTML is that BeautifulSoup reads it as one tag. I need to pull the values from the first `<td>` and the third `<td>`, which would be 1 and 20, respectively.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about this. How can I get BeautifulSoup to read the 1st and 3rd `<td>` tags of each row of the table?

**Update:**

I figured out the problem. I was using `html.parser` instead of the default for BeautifulSoup. Once I switched to the default the problems went away. Also I used the method listed in the answer.

I also found out that the different parsers are very temperamental with broken code. For instance, the default parser refused to read past row 192, but `html5lib` got the job done.So try using `lxml`, `html`, and also `html5lib` if you are having problems parsing the entire table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a nasty piece of HTML you've got there. If we ignore the semantics of table rows and table cells for a moment and treat it as pure XML, its structure looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>1
    <td>
      <td>20
        <td>5%</td>
      </td>
    </td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

BeautifulSoup, however, knows about the semantics of HTML tables, and instead parses it like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>1        <!-- an IMPLICITLY (no closing tag) closed td element -->
  <td>         <!-- as above -->
  <td>20       <!-- as above -->
  <td>5%</td>  <!-- an EXPLICITLY closed td element -->
  </td>        <!-- an error; ignore this -->
  </td>        <!-- as above -->
  </td>        <!-- as above -->
</tr>
```

... so that, as you say, 1 and 20 are in the first and third `td` elements ([not tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8937384/1014938)) respectively.

You can actually get at the contents of these `td` elements like this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<tr><td>1<td><td>20<td>5%</td></td></td></td></tr>")
>>> tr = soup.find("tr")
>>> tr
<tr><td>1</td><td></td><td>20</td><td>5%</td></tr>
>>> td_list = tr.find_all("td")
>>> td_list
[<td>1</td>, <td></td>, <td>20</td>, <td>5%</td>]
>>> td_list[0]  # Python starts counting list items from 0, not 1
<td>1</td>
>>> td_list[0].text
'1'
>>> td_list[2].text
'20'
>>> td_list[3].text
'5%'
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result is `[<td>1<td><td>20<td>5%</td></td></td></td>,<td><td>20<td>5%</td></td></td>,<td>20<td>5%</td></td>,<td>5%</td>]`

Comment: No problem :-) As you can probably work out, with 'html.parser' the HTML is interpreted as well-formed XHTML (as described above), rather than badly-formed HTML, hence the nested `td` elements in your first result.