# What is the text between an HTML element's angled brackets called?

Tags: html, element

In HTML, we have the element `<strong></strong>`. We have the start tag `<strong>` and end tag `</strong>`, but how do we refer to the text in-between the angled brackets?

```
<strong> </strong>
   ^          ^
    these texts
```

So if we remove the `<> and </>` what is the text part of that tag refereed to as? An Identifier? A symbol? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Its content? Node.InnerHTML? Node.InnerText? Node.TextContent?

Comment: I believe that is just referenced as the 'content' of a tag, haha but @j08691 just beat me to it :)

Comment: Hi, an innerHTML element is the text between the start and end tag.

I'm talking about the text INSIDE the tag itself.

Comment: It's the tagName property.

Comment: Thank you very much Havenard, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's the [Tag Name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

You can access it in JavaScript using `Element.tagName()`.

Also, see: [What is the difference between HTML tags and elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937384/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-and-elements)

Answer (score 0):

It is called an `element`, much like other elements such as images, textboxes, and paragraphs. You can also call it a `tag`.

According to W3Schools,

> The  element is used to identify text that is of greater importance than the surrounding text.

https://html.com/tags/strong/

Comment: Hi, I know it's called an element. I know that it's called a tag.

What is the text, inside the tag called? I'm referring to the bit of text, inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hevenard gave me the right answer. The text inside a tag is known as tagName.